# Is MPI_Bcast supposed to work with MPI_IBcast?

Tags: c++, mpi, mpich

As far as I know, [you can freely mix blocking and non-blocking MPI operations on both ends of the communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656350/do-i-need-to-have-a-corresponding-mpiirecv-for-an-mpiisend), meaning that an MPI_Send(...) can be received by an MPI_Ircv(...).

That said, I could not use an MPI_Bcast(...) with an MPI_Ibcast(...), as in the example below:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  MPI_Request req;
  int i;  
  if (world_rank == 0) {
    i = 126;
    MPI_Ibcast(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
    // do other stuff

    MPI_Wait(&req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

  } else { 
    MPI_Bcast(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  return 0;
}
```

Is this supposed to work? I could not find anything related to this information on MPI documentation.

I'm using MPICH 3.3.2 with GCC 10.2.1.

Comment: You cannot mix blocking and non blocking collective operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer to your question: **No**, the code is not supposed to work.

Long answer: we cannot match blocking and nonblocking **collective** calls because,

1. the collective operations does not have `tag` argument. The use of tags for collective operations can prevent certain hardware optimizations. So message matching cannot be possible as in point-to-point operations.
2. Implementation might use different communication algorithms for optimizations in blocking/nonblocking cases. For example, blocking collective operation can be optimised for minimal time to completion.

This is clearly defined in MPI Standard 3.1:

> Unlike point-to-point operations, nonblocking collective operations do
> not match with blocking collective operations, and collective
> operations do not have a tag argument. All processes must call
> collective operations (blocking and nonblocking) in the same order per
> communicator. In particular, once a process calls a collective
> operation, all other processes in the communicator must eventually
> call the same collective operation, and no other collective operation
> with the same communicator in between. This is consistent with the
> ordering rules for blocking collective operations in threaded
> environments.
>
> Rationale. Matching blocking and nonblocking collective operations is
> not allowed because the implementation might use different
> communication algorithms for the two cases. Blocking collective
> operations may be optimized for minimal time to completion, while
> nonblocking collective operations may balance time to completion with
> CPU overhead and asynchronous progression. The use of tags for
> collective operations can prevent certain hardware optimizations. (End
> of rationale.)

Hope this helps!